# Object level (non-pixel dependent) automation for QT-based GUIs?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, automation

I'm looking for some advice and insight on how people approach creating Object-level GUI automation. Technically the type of functionality I am trying to achieve is easily described by [Squish software](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/index.php). I want to be able to simulate Key-Press and Mouse Click events without relying on Platform-specific pixel displays, and screen sizes. I've tried to use tools like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), but unfortunately my application varies too from platform to platform to make reliably re-repeatable tests.

Basically what I am looking for is some advice as to where to look at how 3rd Part (EXTERNAL) programs hook into properties of QT Widgets and other objects. I know a long time ago there was something call [QtObjectInspector](http://web.archive.org/web/20080416072357/http://trolltech.com/products/qt/addon/solutions/catalog/3/Tools/qtobjectinspector/), but this software required you making Source-Level changes to your Qt code to be compatible on top of being unavailable.

If companies like Squish can do it, how are they doing it? Where do you start? I doubt they are looking at very low level memory interactions, sniffing for "Traffic" that looks like QT on each different system, but I may be wrong.

I'm sorry for such a vague question, but I've been researching for over a day and all I can find now is articles about how amazing Squish is.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I looked into QtTestLib, however this doesn't have the "From the outside" kind of access that I am looking for.

Comment: They hook into the running application via DLL injection. GammaRay does that as well and is available under GPL: http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/gammaray/ http://docs.kdab.com/gammaray/ The uses cases it is used for differ though (debugging vs. automation/testing)

Comment: Thank you for that reply, Frank. The definitely gets me on the right foot. I need to look into DLL injection for QT now. I've looked into this for graphical interception, but never running an application like QT, but it makes sense.

Now to find out how complicated to process is!